# How to convert the TRUE value of an IF formula to text when the active row has a checkbox ticked?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an spreadsheet where I have the following template:

- Column A contains tick-boxes
- Column B contains username
- Column C contains custom STRING (it can be anything like "foo")
- Column D contains a formula (IF(C <> '', getID(), '') where a custom UUID would generate when a cell in Column C is not NULL or ""
- Column E contains a concatenate formula which combines C & D when C is not NULL or "" (IF(C <> '', CONCATENATE(C,'-',D), '')

The desired behavior is the following:

If the tick-box is ticked AND the ID is generated (i.e. Column C is not NULL/''), then return ID and then convert the ID from a formula to plain text. If it is not ticked, do nothing.

So far this is what I have:

```
function onEdit(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rw = sheet.getRange("A:A");

  if (rw == 'TRUE') {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("D2:E"); // exclude header
    range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly:true})
    } else if (rw == 'FALSE'){} // do nothing
```

EDIT: I am including an example of my sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qy9kEiNtCmjDe8xUVYTmG9ZlWw_LfgYyAtvuroorz0Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just to clarify, your logic is: if column A is ticked AND column C is not blank, copy and paste the values from columns D and E to the same range to set them permanently? Also, when do you want this to run? (I assume as soon as the tickbox is ticked?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and try to include a minimal example of your spreadsheet and show relevant code; it's not clear what getID() is doing here. You say you want an ID from Col C, but C is a string, and D is the "ID"; please clarify what you're trying to do. I think what you mean is if A and C exist, D and E should be replaced with static values; is that correct?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the comments. What I want is to have any TRUE values (i.e no string NULLs) to be converted to plain text, and any FALSE values (i.e. blanks) to remain as blanks. The behavior of this would be that if column C is not blank and A is ticked, the ID would generate and it would be plain text. If it is blank and/or it is not ticked, to keep the formula in with it bearing a STRING Blank. Sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qy9kEiNtCmjDe8xUVYTmG9ZlWw_LfgYyAtvuroorz0Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you want to check the values of `D2:E`, create a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) from that (not `A:A`), and [loop through each row](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) comparing the values. In your example, `rw` is a two dimensional array of all of the values in `A:A`; this does not act as an 'if true for this row, then do this for that row' as you might expect from Sheets formulas. For information on how Google Apps Script comparisons work, look up Javascript, and keep in mind the values (see GAS' docs).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following does what you need:

```js
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 1.0){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var desc = sheet.getRange("C" + row).getValue() != '';
    var existingID = sheet.getRange("D" + row).getValue() != ''; // Only useful if you don't want to override an existing ID
    
    if (desc && e.value == 'TRUE' && !existingID) sheet.getRange("D" + row).setValue(getID()); // If you want to override remove the `!existingId` condition
    else sheet.getRange("D" + row).setValue(''); // If you don't want to delete the ID in case the checkbox is unchecked, remove this line
  }
  
  /* If you want to remove the ID in case the description is removed, 
   * you need some code here that checks if e.range.getColumn() is 3, 
   * and then removes the ID if the new value is empty. 
   * You can probably re-use most of the above for this. 
   * */
}
```

Note: this assumes you keep using the current formula for column E, but you could also set either the formula or the value via the code above by duplicating the line that assigns (or removes, if relevant) the value for range `"E" + row`.